# Publishing not push the database initialisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We managed to push the web and `database` `publish` previously into `Azure` (production environment - not live) via **Web Deploy** from `VS 2017`. Since we have a new database structure and web content so we decide to delete all the tables in a production environment and do the publishing again from the beginning.

The publishing running ok BUT NO database data initialisation (sample data that we defined in DbInitializer.cs) .. ONLY the database structure. In the Publish Settings, we can see Database DefaultConnection and EF Migrations ApplicationDBContext both being ticked.

Any ideas?

Environment:

```
- .Net Core 2.1 
 - SQL Server 
 - Azure App Service
```

**Program.cs:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
                    var dbInitializerLogger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DbInitializer>>();

                    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                    // DbInitializer.Initialize(context, );

                    DbInitializer.Initialize(context, userManager, roleManager, dbInitializerLogger).Wait();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }
```

**DBInitializer.cs:**

```
public class DbInitializer
    {
        private static Host host;

        public static async Task Initialize(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, ILogger<DbInitializer> logger)
        {
            //context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // Look for any users.
            if (context.Users.Any())
            {
                return; // DB has been seeded
            }

            await CreateDefaultUserAndRoleForApplication(userManager, roleManager, logger);

            await CreateDefaultUserTableData(context, userManager, logger);
        }

 ...

}
```

Comment: I suggest you change the connectionstring to `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb`, and start your project to check whether the datbase and data are set up correctly. In addition, enable `Diagnostics logs` in Azure App Service to check whether there is any error during `DbInitializer`.

Comment: @TaoZhou are you referring this for app settings.json ? It’s on the machine already and it’s pointing to localdb. The production I assume will get replaced automatically to Azure databAse when you do the Publishing.

Comment: I know it will be replaced during publishing, I suggest to check whether there is any error happen while running `DbInitializer`. As my test, if there is no error, the data will be seed correctly.

Comment: @TaoZhou On the dev, we did multiple times by deleting all tables in local  databases including EF history as well as Migrations folder and it did the datainitialisation including sample data and worked OK. I don’t think it’s an issue with the code

Comment: Add more log to `DbInitializer` to log the code step by step. Try to make a test with [HostInAzureWebApp](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/master/Hosting/HostInAzureWebApp).

Comment: @TaoZhou thanks will do. I assume you want me published into current Azure app service? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is my test project which works for publishing to azure app service.

Comment: @TaoZhou Managed to get your code working both on Dev and Azure (with a new App Service and SQL database). Not sure why my one is not working?!?! We checked the Diagnostic Logs ... didn't see any errors?

Comment: @TaoZhou Didn't see in Log Streams for Info/Errors etc etc ?!?! Did the Diagnostic Log as per request.

Comment: Thanks @TaoZhou ... you are right. The issue is relating on DBInitializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it's related on the current code (dev) for DbInitializer as we override the SaveChangesAsync stuff.